# How to upgrade openshift default maven version from 3.0.4 to 3.1.0?

Tags: maven, openshift

The maven plugin frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23 requires maven 3.1.0 but openshift has default 3.0.4.

*Below is Maven Error on "git push" to openshift:*

```
remote: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:0.0.23:install-node
-and-npm (install node and npm) on project taxtab-controllers: The plugin com.github.eirslett:fronte
nd-maven-plugin:0.0.23 **requires Maven version 3.1.0** -> [Help 1]
```

*I tried below steps to fix the build:*

1. I installed latest maven 3.3.1 in `$OPENSHIFT_HOMEDIR\app-root\runtime\apache-maven`.
2. Tried adding adding the below exports in both action hooks : pre_build and build, but still not working.

`export M2_HOME=/var/lib/openshift/5497cdff4382ec255f00002c/app-root/runtime/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.1
 export M2=$M2_HOME/bin
 export PATH=$M2:$PATH`

I also tried adding the `.bash_profile` in `~/app-root/data/` with above variable settings, still not working.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. Downgrading one version of the plugin solved the issue:

```
<groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
<artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.0.22</version>
```

Instead of 0.0.23

However, I run then into the next issue, which is npm install not working due to lack of root.